# ViewModels, CQRS and Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, cqrs

I am trying to understand how to probably make use of a view model, a command and the database entity

At the moment I think there is a lot of manual mapping between this, and I am unsure if I should use a tool like AutoMapper to map `ViewModel <-> Command <-> Entity` when there is a lot of properties (like 10-15).

Take this example (written quickly in notepad, may not compile - in my real applicaiton I use dependency injection and IoC):

```
public class Student {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string AnoterProperty { get; set; }
    public string AnoterProperty2 { get; set; }     
    public string AnoterProperty3 { get; set; }    
    public string AnoterProperty4 { get; set; }    
    public string AnoterProperty5 { get; set; }    

    public int StudentTypeId { get; set; }
    public StudentType StudentType { get; set; } // one-to-many
}

public class CreateStudentViewModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DropDownList StudentTypes { get; set; }
}

public class DropDownList {
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class CreateStudent {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StudentTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class HandleCreateStudentCommand {

    public void Execute(CreateStudent command) {
        var student = new Student {
            Name = command.Name,
            StudentTypeId = command.StudentTypeId
        };

        // add to database
    }

}

public class StudentController {

    public ActionResult Create() {
        var model = new CreateStudentViewModel {
            StudentTypes = new DropDownList { 
               Items = // fetch student types from database 
            }
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Create(CreateStudentViewModel model) {
        var command = new CreateStudent {
            Name = model.Name,
            StudentTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(model.Items.SelectedValue);
        };

        var commandHandler = new HandleCreateStudentCommand();
        commandHandler.Execute(command);
    }

}
```

What worries me here is that I do a lot of manual mapping between the different parts. And this example only contains a few properties.

I am especially worried about a possible update command which will most likely contain all possible properties of the student entity.

Is there a neat solution, or should I go with AutoMapper and map from `ViewModel <-> Command` and `Command <-> Entity`?

Comment: just to clearify: Command = CQRS Command and ViewModel is ReadModel? Or is this MVC and the CQRS tag and title is missleading? Why is there a MVVM tag?

Comment: I use my `CreateStudentViewModel` to expose the properties that should be able to choose/fill in the view. :-) I would possible create a `StudentViewModel` for only displaying data.

Comment: Oh, sorry - added asp.net mvc tag!

Comment: So this is just MVC right? Nothing at all to do with MVVM or CQRS

Comment: A I see - there is a bit CQRS in the Create Action - sorry

Comment: To give an answer: no I would not use any auto-tools. Instead I would maybe write Extension-Methods or static conversation methods/constructers in the ViewModel classes to help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to deal with less classes and mappings / projections / conversions:

For all the views used in the *WRITE-SIDE* of your application (the views that allow the user to submit a form or so), let the Command to be their Model (View Model).

That is, you can have:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateStudent command) {
    commandHandler.Execute(command);
}
```

As for the *get action*, I see that you have to populate a drop-down list...

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create() {
    // var model = create the view model somehow
    return View(model);
}
```

Now, as for the model in the latter snippet, you may have these options (and perhaps others):

- let the Command object (CreateStudent) be the  model of the view (as the view is a... view for a command, a view for a request) and pass the items for the drop-down using the *ViewBag*
- derive from CreateStudent command just to make of it a view model that can also hold the items for the drop-down

Notice that there is no need to add the suffix "Command" to your command object. Just give it a name that means *doSomething* - a verb phrase (verb + object) - and it should be fine.

In the end, some *command* objects really are the models for some views - no need to define another view-models for those and then have a lot of duplication etc.

Also, you may find these interesting:

- http://cqrs.nu/Faq
- http://cqrsjourney.github.io/
- https://github.com/mspnp/cqrs-journey-code/tree/master/source/Conference

Comment: This seeem like a good approach, I will probably end up with deriving from the command to simple view model to hold the drop down items. I hope I wont run into problems like simple client-side validating of this view model. (The command is validated with business rules before comitted.)

Comment: I mean: simple client-side validating of the command, when its not a model for it self anymore